# How to use CollapsingToolbarLayout instead of using application theme action bar for specific activity?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, app-themes

I am using an app theme for my application where action bar flag is true for that theme. And all of my activity are showing the same action bar.

How can I use CollapsingToolbarLayout for any specific activity instead of using main app theme action bar?

I have added below code in my activity class:

```
  final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(cheeseName);
```

And this is my layout:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

But it's not working, My activity always showing the app theme action bar.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

xml file

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/your_image"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
                android:title="Collapsing Toolbar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: what are you getting ?

Comment: You have not used any image for collapsing. use image it will work

Answer (score 1):

try this: in your xml layout...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="218dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|enterAlwaysCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/google_thumb"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

       //this is the layout that you want under collapsing toolbar
        <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In your `Activity`

```
    public class Toolbar_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar;
    Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle("TITLE");
    }
}
```

then in your manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Toolbar_activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

@0xAliHn,

Its because your not applying any theme to `CollapsingToolbarLayout`

just create a custome theme that you want and apply it to your `AppBarLayout`

other wise it will inherit the same theme that you have used inside your `Androidmenifest.xml`

Comment: I have used this `android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"` in my AppBarlayout

Answer (score 0):

If you use `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, you need set `Toolbar` inside it as action bar. you can work around for this situation, hide your action bar(in this case main toolbar) you use for all activity. After that use your code above

```
final Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Sorry if I don't understand what do you want correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you should set the new theme in mainifest like this

```
<activity android:name=".your activity" android:theme="xxxx"></activity>
```

Comment: increase your answer please